# Is there a way to upgrade an existing bathroom light exhaust fan to include heater without having to rewire the entire switch?

Tags: exhaust-fan

I need to upgrade an existing bathroom light exhaust fan to include heater, however there is only one wire/switch going to the current exhaust fan which runs both the light and the exhaust fan.

Is there a method I can do this without having to rewire?

I need to be able to run the light and exhaust fan without the heater running and visa versa. It would be incredibly difficult to have to run a new wires up to the exhaust fan.  I would have no access to the ceiling via the attic and the current switch is on a half wall.

I have done google searches looking for an exhaust fan that has a heater that is controlled by a remote but it appears that there is no such thing surprisingly

Is there  a way to wire in a second switch with out having to go through walls?

Comment: If you want separate power for the heater you need to supply separate power to it.  There may be a work around if you could access the attic space.

Comment: This would be a shopping question and they are off topic here.

Comment: I took the shopping part out.

Comment: I suspect you'll find out that your bigger problem is lack of adequate power to run that heater and anything else in the bathroom without tripping a breaker unless you run a whole new circuit.

Comment: @Ecnerwal is correct. A standard light and exhaust fan might use 100W and be able to easily share a circuit with receptacles in the same bathroom or with lights elsewhere in the house, etc. (there are code rules regarding the details). But a heater should always be on a circuit by itself (except for sharing with integral fan & light, of course) as it will typically be designed to use a full 15A circuit.

Comment: What's driving you to have a heater as part of the bath fan?

Comment: The bathroom is the master suite and above the garage it gets cold in that room during winter

Comment: @LewisJBartlett -- have you considered insulating + air-sealing the garage ceiling? Throwing watts at an envelope defect is generally not a good idea...

Comment: An infrared parabolic heat lamp (either white or red) is common in bathrooms. They are usually 250 watt, pointing down from the ceiling.